# Dynamically updating an array of input fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of input fields:

```
<input name="feiertag[]" onchange=updateTag("2013-09-02") type="text" id="feiertag[]" value="">
<input name="feiertag[]" onchange=updateTag("2013-09-03") type="text" id="feiertag[]" value="">
<input name="feiertag[]" onchange=updateTag("2013-09-04")  type="text" id="feiertag[]" value="">
<input name="feiertag[]" onchange=updateTag("2013-09-05")  type="text" id="feiertag[]" value="">
```

I want to update the database right after the changing the field value, how can I get ajax dinamically update
my database as soon as one of the fields are changed.

```
function updateTag(datum)
{

var feiertag=$_POST['feiertag'][$i];

$.ajax({ url: "update_tag.php?datum="+datum+"&feiertag="+feiertag,
data: {"datumf":datumf,"feiertag":feiertag},
 type: 'get',
});
}
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing PHP and Javascript. `$_POST['feiertag'][$i];` is PHP code and needs to run on the server.

Comment: `$i`..where did that come from???

Comment: You need to put an `id` for each field and then send it via `updateTag("2013-09-02", yourid)`. Then you can replace that `$_POST['feiertag'][$i];` which is wrong with the id that you will get from argument.